# How to find readonly textfields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i find readonly textfields in a form..i treied this..but it is not working..

```
$('input[readonly="readonly"]').each(function() 
{
$(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me, both:

```
console.log($('input[readonly="readonly"]'));
```

and

```
console.log($('input[readonly]'))
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tava6/)

---

Edit:

The problem with your code is that it is missing an ending `)`. See this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tava6/1/):

```
$('input[readonly="readonly"]').each(function() 
{
    $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
});
```

---

Regarding your comment question about setting `readonly` dynamically then searching for the input:

```
$('input[name="country"]').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

$('input[readonly="readonly"]').each(function()
{
    $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
});
```

[See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/tava6/2/)

Comment: Does that work if the "readonly" property is set programmatically, and not as an attribute on the HTML element directly?

Comment: isecond one is working.i want to put one more condition.get all readonly textfields in which id is not ending with "-date".How can i include it??

Comment: Shouldn't `readonly` be set/modified using `.prop` instead of `.attr` in jQuery 1.6?

Comment: in this case you have to use `$('input:not([id$="-date"])')`. If you want, post another question so I can give you an full answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('input').filter(function() { return !!$(this).prop('readonly'); }).each(function() {
  // ...
});
```

You could also just check the property in the body of the ".each()" callback:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).prop('readonly')) return;
  // ... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input[readonly]').each(function() 
{
    $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
}
```

Could be because not every browser makes the value readonly but jus nothing.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8aRg8/

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('[readonly]')) alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: i want to put one more condition.get all readonly textfields in which id is not ending with "-date".How can i include it??

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to use this as a selector: `input[readonly]`

At least chrome will see input as readonly as long as it has the attribute, no matter what the value is.